# Option select in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to do a option select in Objective-C similar to HTML, and I search for all Google and I don't find nothing about how I can do this.
Any idea to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Pickers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html) (scroll down until you find Pickers), they are the iOS equivalent of HTML option select.

Reference doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842).

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into using a `UITableView` and populate that with a list. Then you can use the table view delegate methods to detect when one of the cells is pressed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html